# C#: How to forbid implicit cast from child to parent class (i.e. inheritance as composition vs. is-kind-of)?

Tags: c#, .net

### Summary

Let's say I have two C# 4.0 classes, one inheriting from the other:

```
class ParentKey {}
class ChildKey : ParentKey {}
```

I want the compiler to issue an error if I try this:

```
ChildKey c = new ChildKey();
ParentKey p = c; // I want compiler error here!
```

Essentially, I want to use inheritance **for reusability purposes**, but I want to **avoid polymorphic behavior** (or more specifically, assign compatibility) that normally comes with it. Similar to C++ private inheritance.

---

### Example

Specifically, I'd like to avoid accidentally mixing ParentKey and ChildKey when used as keys of some container (since their implementations of GetHashCode() or Equals() might be incompatible). For example:

```
Dictionary<ParentKey, object> d = new Dictionary<ParentKey, object>();
d.Add(new ChildKey(), new object()); // I want compiler error here!
```

---

### What I Tried

Now, I know I can use composition to avoid the inheritance altogether, but I'd like to avoid the verbosity that comes with this solution (my ParentKey can be quite complex, and there may be many levels of inheritance hierarchy).

Another solution is to always use tailor-made IEqualityComparer, or to explicitly create new ParentKey based on the ChildKey prior passing to the container, but both of these are easy to forget, and may be comparatively hard to diagnose at run-time.

Attempting to make the conversion explicit...

```
class ChildKey : ParentKey {
    public static explicit operator ParentKey(ChildKey c) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

...yielded compiler error CS0553: *user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed.*

Struct inheritance would be ideal here (so the "end" portion of ChildKey is "cut-off" when passed to something that is declared as ParentKey), but this is not supported in C# either.

Am I missing something obvious here? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your concerns about GetHashCode() and Equals() could be overcome by overriding those methods and making sure the two objects are the same type. Of course it seems it needs to be said by using inheritance a ChildKey IS a ParentKey. This basic fact of inheritance cannot be avoided.  You could also override the Equals() method and return NULL if the objects are not the same Type.  Furthermore you could have ChildKey have a ParentKey property and return that instead.

Comment: Can the behaviour or logic you want to resuse be separated into a separate behavioural class (or perhaps an interface can be used and some implementation passed in... using composition)?

Comment: Just pointing out the Liskov Substitution principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: "Your concerns about GetHashCode() and Equals() could be overcome by overriding those methods and making sure the two objects are the same type."

Unfortunately, there is no "other" object for GetHashCode(), so there is nothing to compare the type of "this" object to. Even if it were, cases can be constructed where this would not work - for example Dictionary<ParentKey, object> that contains ONLY ChildKey objects - some objects would be considered different even though they are equal when "cut down" to their ParentKey portion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're working directly against the by-design purpose of the type system, which is to make it *always possible* to assign a more-derived type to a variable of a less-derived type. (Moreoever: suppose you did somehow manage to prevent implicit reference conversions from Derived to Base -- what stops you from converting Derived *to object* and then explicitly converting object to Base? It seems perverse to prohibit something at compile time that we cannot prevent at runtime.)

I agree that from a language design perspective, it is possible to create a language which avoids conflating *code reuse via inheritance* with *subtype polymorphism*. However, we chose to conflate those two things a long, long time ago. You're going to have to either live with that choice, or use a different language that gives you the feature you want. (*)

My advice: **stop spitting into the wind**. Either use composition, or carefully craft your Equals and GetHashCode methods so that everyone plays together nicely.

(All that said, I have often shared your frustration that reuse via composition has so much verbose "ceremony" around it. It would be great if we could find a way to lower the syntactic burden of composition.)

---

(*) I am definitely not an expert on Eiffel; that said, your idea seems to me to be like the Eiffel concept of **non-conforming inheritance**. Perhaps an expert on Eiffel would like to comment on this?

Comment: Hi Eric,

"You're working directly against the by-design purpose of the type system..."

If this is a design decision made by C#, that's fine. Not being a C# expert, I was merely asking how to accomplish in C# what can be done fairly simply in C++.

"...what stops you from converting Derived to object and then explicitly converting object to Base"

Nothing, that's not the point. I just want is to be warned by the compiler if I don't do an explicit conversion (not just cast), and that should work selectively - only for classes that I say should behave that way.

Comment: "carefully craft your Equals and GetHashCode"

Unfortunately, the meaning of Equals and GetHashCode changes depending on the enclosing container. In the Dictionary<ParentKey, object> these methods (should) mean one thing and in Dictionary<ChildKey, object> something else...

Comment: @Branko: Perhaps the problem is that the responsibility for determining equality is being put in the wrong place. You know that you can pass a custom equality comparer to a dictionary, right? If you want to have two different dictionaries with two different equality policies for the same data, you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is what I ended up doing. The theoretical "C++ solution" (with private inheritance) is still "better" (although, I suspect, less performant due memory pressure of all these "chopped off" keys) in a sense that the compiler would warn me if I do something I was not supposed to do. We'll need to be careful to always use the right IEqualityComparer and make sure we test all our edge cases instead of relying on the compiler...

Comment: About that first parenthetical, I just want to point out that disallowing _implicit_ conversion does not mean you wouldn't be able to convert. You would just need to be converting on purpose. Not that that applies to C# because you still can't do it there.

Comment: Many things are prohibited at compile time that are posible at run time. One such example is `(ushort[])(object)new short[] { 0, -1 }` which works fine, but fails to compile if you remove the seemingly-redundant cast to `object`.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
class BaseKey
{
    // all functionality here
}

class ParentKey : BaseKey
{}

class ChildKey : BaseKey
{}
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately, my dictionary would then have to be Dictionary<BaseKey, object>, which essentially brings us back to the original problem...

Comment: Why? As I see from your sample you need a `Dictionary<ParentKey, object>`

Comment: As per your class hierarchy, I can't convert ChildKey into ParentKey so I can't put it into Dictionary<ParentKey, object>.

Comment: I want to be able to put ChildKey in the dictionary, but I want it to be COMPARED as it is actually ParentKey. I was aware there are ways to solve this (see "What I Tried" section), but all these solutions required the programmer to manually check the code. I was simply wondering if there was a way for C# compiler to do that for the programmer, as possible in some other languages - we have a lot of edge cases, so I was concerned we might not cover all of them with unit tests...

Comment: Clarification... I wasn't concerned with how to implement the correct comparison, I was concerned with how to ENSURE that correct comparison is used in every case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public struct Exclusive<T>
{
   public Exclusive(T item)
   {
     if (c.GetType () != typeof(ParentKey))
       throw new Exception (); // I want compiler error here!
     Item = item;
   }
   public T Item{get; private set;}
   // todo: add implicit cast to T
   // todo: add forcing non-null to get_Item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a shortcoming of the C# (and C++) language, I hope it will be fixed (but doubt it ..)

In my (not common) opinion polymorphism is an anti pattern, basically a bad idea that somehow became popular, this becomes more and more obvious the more functional code you write.

On the other hand, extension is an invaluable coding mechanism and trying to replicate it with composition just so you can avoid polymorphism is tedious and bug prone and doesn't scale.

(as a side note, IMO it would not be hard to add this to the language, ie an "extends" keyword `class ChildKey extends ParentKey { ... }` etc)

What I do is use the "curiously recurring template pattern"

```
abstract class KeyBase<TDerived> { /* common functionality here */ }
class Key : KeyBase<Key> { /* inherit common functionality */ }
```

Of course this does not stop a user from doing

```
Key c = new Key();
KeyBase<Key> p = c;
```

But it has a few advantages:

- It becomes more explicit from from the template argument that the intention is extension and that no `KeyBase<Key>` variables should be declared.
- `KeyBase` methods can now accept and return `TDerived`, this is especially useful when dealing with immutable classes
- You can easily create different `Key` types (`KeyEx`) which have identical API but are different types (`typeof(Key)!=typeof(KeyEx)`).